# How can I get an OS X Server to assign IP addresses?

Tags: macos, network, mac-mini, osx-server

I am trying to connect a couple of devices via Ethernet to a Mac Mini acting as a server. The OS X Server app is running, DHCP is enabled, and this was working fine, but it doesn't seem to be working at all today.

The Mac Mini is running Server version 4.1 on OS X 10.10.4. I've connected each one of the devices to a Mac Mini which was sharing the connection via Ethernet, therefore assigning IP addresses, and this worked.

I've tried disabling and re-enabling DHCP on the Server app, then tried rebooting, but no joy.

How can I get DHCP working?

Comment: Are the devices connected to a network in which a router is providing DHCP addresses? If so, that might be trumping the server.app

Comment: Good question,  should've mentioned that before. I tried connecting 2 devices using an 8 port switch, then connecting 1 device directly to the mac mini's Ethernet port

Comment: So to be sure, there is no other device providing DHCP on the network?

Comment: Very good point. I actually had wifi enabled and the mac mini was connected to a wifi router providing DHCP. I've disabled that now so the only network connection goes through Ethernet. I've connected the switch and my macbook to the switch and I can connect to the mac mini this way. I've disabled Internet sharing via Ethernet on my macbook to make sure it's not assigning IPs. The part that is strange though is that the Server app is still not listing DHCP clients(although I'm connected) and it doesn't see the other 2 devices connected via Ethernet :/ Any hints on what I might be missing ?